# haskell TicTacToe game

Tags: function, haskell, tic-tac-toe

I am trying to build a tic tac toe game in haskell and I am having trouble with a function `haswon`. The function should return `True` if for a given player `p` and the game board `bs`, he has already won the game, and `False` otherwise.

Here is the code:

```
Int -> [((Int,Int),Int)] -> Bool
haswon p [((a,d), x), ((b,e), y), ((c,f), z)] = (x == y && y == z && x == p) && ( ((a == b) && (b == c)) || ((d == e) && (e == f)) || ( (a == d) && (b == e) && (c == f) && (a /= b) && (b /= c)) || ( (a == f) && (c == d) && (b==e)&&(a/=b)&&(b/=c)) )
```

Could you please tell me how can I generalize this for an input list that is bigger than 3 elements?
For instance, the input could be : `[((1,1),1), ((1,2),1), ((2,1),2), ((2,2),2), ((3,1),1), ((3,2),1), ((3,3),2)]`.
Thank you.

Comment: There are three types of combinations that make a player win - row, column and diagonal. Maybe start with generalizing each and combining them together?

Answer (score 0):

> Here is the code:

Here's my take at it:

Let's define *proper* data types first:

```
data Player = Black | White deriving (Eq, Show)
data Position = Position Int Int deriving (Eq, Show)
data Move = Move { position :: Position, player :: Player } deriving (Eq, Show)
```

Now the actual function just counts the lines that qualify for winning

```
hasWon :: Player -> [Move] -> Bool
hasWon p ms = (length $ winningLines p ms) > 0
```

The winning lines generation is one big comprehension:

```
winningLines p ms = [(x,y,z) | x <- ms,
                               y <- ms,
                               z <- ms,
                               oneLine (position x) (position y) (position z),
                               samePlayer (player x) (player y) (player z),
                               x /= y,
                               y /= z,
                               x /= z
                     ]

samePlayer px py pz = px == py && py == pz

oneLine (Position x1 y1) (Position x2 y2) (Position x3 y3) = sameRow || sameCol
    where
        sameRow = (y1 == y2 && y2 == y3)
        sameCol = (x1 == x2 && x2 == x3)
```

And finally some testing:

```
moves = [
    Move (Position 1 1) White,
    Move (Position 2 1) White,
    Move (Position 3 1) White
    ]

main :: IO ()
main = do
    print $ hasWon White moves
    print $ winningLines White moves
```

The solution is only using the basics, so you should be able to understand it quite easily and add your own fixes; it's still missing diagonals (easy to add), and it's counting all the lines 6 times (because it's taking all permutations into account; easy to fix with `Ord` instance for position and only taking a "sorted triple" into account).

Of course this is not the only way to do it; one notable alternative would be to put it into an array in-place, and then find the solution iteratively. I think the Prolog-esque declarative style just fits Haskell better, though.